# htaccess mod_rewrite query string path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, path, url-rewriting, query-string

I've seen and implemented rewrite urls that convert query strings to paths and vice versa. I'm still not very good at writing custom rules and I haven't seen an example where the query string's converted path is re-written as the first subdirectory of a URL.

Using htaccess rewrite rules, is this possible?
www.website.com/?d=test rewrites to www.website.com/test and
www.website.com/about/?d=test rewrites to www.website.com/test/about and
www.website.com/about/overview/?d=test rewrites to www.website.com/test/about/overview

Comment: It is, it's just not typically useful - paths are often rewritten to query strings so that the back-end can process them more conveniently while the URLs look more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^d=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ %1/$1? [L]
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.